# Database form as QGIS plugin with PyQGIS and QtDesigner

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, combo-box

I try to build a QGIS plugin to add data into a SpatiaLite database. All relevant tables are load into the QGIS Layers Panel.
At first, I want to select a feature in `table_1`. This table has geometries and could also select in map canvas. I would specify this in a `QgsFeatureListComboBox`. My approach is

```
self.dlg.mFeatureListComboBox_losp.setSourceLayer(table_1)
```

With this, I get the combo box and can choose a feature. But how to select the feature by the combobox and work with this feature and the information?

Comment: If your aim is to choose a feature using a combobox, `QgsFeaturePickerWidget` is more useful. You can get selected feature easily by it. Do you have any specific reason for using `QgsFeatureListComboBox`?

Comment: Yes my aim is to choose a feature, receive data and copy the data of one field by this feature into an other table in the database. There I want to collect some ofer data. The copy of the data from one field is to have the relationship between the tables. I will try the `QgsFeaturePickerWidget`but how to receive the relevant informations and put it in the other tables?

Comment: I made some effort but couldn't find a solution using `QgsFeatureListComboBox`. Therefore, I will add a solution using `QgsFeaturePickerWidget`.

Answer (score 10):

If you use `QgsFeaturePickerWidget` instead of `QgsFeatureListComboBox`, you can get the selected feature in the combobox easily.

Sample script for the plugin:

```
def run(self):

    ...
    ...

    layer = self.iface.activeLayer()

    picker = self.dlg.mFeaturePickerWidget
    picker.setLayer(layer)
    picker.setDisplayExpression('$id') #show ids in combobox

    def select_feature():
        layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
        layer.removeSelection()
        
        feature = picker.feature()

        # Do whatever you need with feature

        # For example, select the feature
        layer.select(feature.id())


    button = self.dlg.pushButton
    button.clicked.connect(select_feature)

    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()

    ...
    ...
```

Using the sample script, after you choose a feature id in combobox, you can get all attributes and geometry of the feature using `picker.feature()`.

[image]