# QgsFeaturePickerWidget in Qt Designer

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qt-designer

I have this code in my dialog_box_dialog.py,

```
    # Connect the accepted() signal of the OK button to the custom slot
    self.Button.accepted.connect(self.onAccept)

@pyqtSlot()
def updateFeatures(self):
    selected_layer = self.Original_Layer.currentLayer()
    selected_field = self.Field.currentField()
    if selected_layer and selected_field:
        self.Feature_Picker.setLayer(selected_layer)
        self.Feature_Picker.setDisplayExpression(selected_field)

def openEditDialog(self):
    # Create and show the Edit Dialog Box when the Edit button is clicked
    self.edit_dialog = EditDialog()
    self.edit_dialog.show()

def onAccept(self):
```

and i have this code in my dialog_box.py,

```
    def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    layer = self.iface.activeLayer()

    Feature_Picker = self.dlg.mFeaturePickerWidget
    Feature_Picker.setLayer(layer)
    Feature_Picker.setDisplayExpression('$id') #show ids in combobox

    # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
    # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
    if self.first_start == True:
        self.first_start = False
        self.dlg = DummyDialogBoxDialog()

    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
        # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
        # substitute with your code.
        pass
```

I want to create something like this [Database form as QGIS plugin with PyQGIS and QtDesigner](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409517/database-form-as-qgis-plugin-with-pyqgis-and-qtdesigner/409556#409556) where when i already chose layer, field and feature, it will zoom/fly to/go to the data that i chose but i stuck at the feature. I use QgsFeaturePickerWidget.

Can someone help me to solve it?

Comment: Please do not delete and re-ask questions that have been closed.  We need you to edit the original so that it can be reviewed by the community to determine whether it is ready to receive answers.