# Zoom in Qt Designer using QgsFeaturePickerWidget

Tags: pyqgis, features, qt-designer

I have this code in my dialog_box_dialog.py,

```
# Connect the accepted() signal of the OK button to the custom slot
self.Button.accepted.connect(self.onAccept)

@pyqtSlot()
def updateFeatures(self):
    selected_layer = self.Original_Layer.currentLayer()
    selected_field = self.Field.currentField()
    if selected_layer and selected_field:
        self.Feature_Picker.setLayer(selected_layer)
        self.Feature_Picker.setDisplayExpression(selected_field)

def openEditDialog(self):
    # Create and show the Edit Dialog Box when the Edit button is clicked
    self.edit_dialog = EditDialog()
    self.edit_dialog.show()

def onAccept(self):
```

and i have this code in my dialog_box.py,

```
def run(self):
"""Run method that performs all the real work"""

# Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
# Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
if self.first_start == True:
    self.first_start = False
    self.dlg = DummyDialogBoxDialog()

# show the dialog
self.dlg.show()
# Run the dialog event loop
result = self.dlg.exec_()
# See if OK was pressed
if result:
    # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
    # substitute with your code.
    pass
```

I want to create something like this [Database form as QGIS plugin with PyQGIS and QtDesigner](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409517/database-form-as-qgis-plugin-with-pyqgis-and-qtdesigner) where when i already chose layer, field and feature, it will zoom/fly to/go to the data that i chose but i stuck at the feature. I use QgsFeaturePickerWidget.

Can someone help me to solve it?

Comment: Please do not delete and re-ask questions.  We need you to edit the original so that it may be reviewed by the community to determine whether it is ready to receive answers.

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.